# How to configure versioning setting for my document management

Tags: sharepoint, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I would like to prepare a document management, the properties of each document is :

```
    Doc no        Revision       Created Date
```

My problem is major revision of each document starts from: 00
Second revision is: 01
Third revision is:02

Like below:

```
  Docno             Revision   Created Date
 Doc-0001            00          01-may-19
                     01          05-may-19
                     02          08-may-19
```

While Major Version setting of SharePoint starts from : 1
Second version is:2
Third version is:3

Now i do not know how i have to configure versioning setting of SharePoint because major version starts from:1
While i need major version starts from :0

I do not know is better i create a column for revision and manually change it or i can use versioning function of SharePoint some way?

Answer (score 1):

The versioning in SharePoint works as per Industry standards. Try to use it as much and as far as you can rather than creating your own custom versioning system.

Keep in mind when you create your own you need to take into consideration as: maintaining history log, rollback to any previous version, snapshot of all versions, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I do not want to change this rule. I would like to know how i can solve my problem. Because according to the documentation procedure has been defined by my owner first major/official revision should starts from 0. I was thinking if i create a new calculated column (New Revision) and put a formula for it =version-1, But i do not know this solve my problem or no? I appreciate for any recommend.

Comment: the version should start from 0.1 (draft) and not 0